# chart.js and asynchronous loading

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I tried to get another hold on JS and figured I would start playing around with chart.js to visualize some data.

This is what I copied and tweaked for now:

```js
const label =[];
const cases = [];

fetch('https://rki.marlon-lueckert.de/api/states')
    .then(response => {
      if(response.ok) return response.json();
      throw new Error(response.statusText)  // throw an error if there's something wrong with the response
    })
    .then(function handleData(data) {
      for (var i=0; i<data.states.length; i++) {
        label.push(data.states[i].name)
        cases.push(data.states[i].count)
        console.log(data.states[i].name)
        console.log(data.states[i].count)
      }
    });

chartIt();
async function chartIt() {
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: label,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Covid-19 cases',
            data: cases,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Covid-19 Charts</title>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-hZf9Qhp3rlDJBvAKvmiG+goaaKRZA6LKUO35oK6EsM0/kjPK32Yw7URqrq3Q+Nvbbt8Usss+IekL7CRn83dYmw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="chartData.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="chart" style="position: relative; height:80vh; width:100vw">
      
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Data is visualized correctly but only after resizing the page. I figured it has to do with asynchronous functions. But I'm completely lost regarding fixing this.

Also: not sure what to do with the "when error occurs" part in my data fetching to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to set the chart `width` and `height` to `100%`. I also removed the logging so that you can clearly see the results. i.e.

`<div class="chart" style="position: relative; height:80vh; width:100vw"></div>`

to

`<div class="chart" style="height:100%; width:100%"></div>`

With regards to the error code, you should probably use a `catch` on the chain.

e.g.

```js
const label = [];
const cases = [];

fetch('https://rki.marlon-lueckert.de/api/states').then(response => {
    if (response.ok) return response.json();
    throw new Error(response.statusText) // throw an error if there's something wrong with the response
}).then(data => {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.states.length; i++) {
        label.push(data.states[i].name)
        cases.push(data.states[i].count)
    }
    chartIt();
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
});

async function chartIt() {
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: label,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Covid-19 cases',
                data: cases,
                backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'],
                borderColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Covid-19 Charts</title>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-hZf9Qhp3rlDJBvAKvmiG+goaaKRZA6LKUO35oK6EsM0/kjPK32Yw7URqrq3Q+Nvbbt8Usss+IekL7CRn83dYmw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="chartData.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="chart" style="height:100%; width:100%">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But this doesn't fix the issue of the data only being shown after resizing the page. I think it is based on some issue that the data is processed after the DOM was rendered and it needs to "re-render" to show the correct data.

Comment: Ah - ok, just move the `chartIt()` call into the `fetch` functionality so that it is called after the data has successfully loaded. see my edit.